# How can I break up an XML document into multiple documents and exclude specific child nodes from the result tree using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a rather large XML file that I want to break up into smaller files. I can do this for the most part using `xsl:result-document` and `xsl:copy-of`. However, I do not want to copy specific child nodes into the result tree. Here is an example of the structure I am working with:

```
<root>
    <a id="parent_node1">
        <!-- stuff I want to copy into the parent_node1 tree -->
        <a id="child_node1">
            <!-- stuff I want to copy into the child_node1 tree -->
            <a id="descendant_node1">
                <!-- stuff I want to copy into the descendant_node1 tree -->
            </a>
        </a>
    </a>
    <a id="parent_node2">
        ...
    </a>
    ...
</root>
```

The result I want is to copy each `<a>` node into a separate document while excluding any `<a>` child nodes. When I do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="a">
        <xsl:result-document href="a_{@id}.xml>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            ...
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I end up with undesirable child nodes in the output. So, I have a couple questions.

- How can I process this large XML in the way I want to?
- What would I need to do if I wanted to change something like the value of a specific attribute when processing?

Comment: The example XML is not well-formed!

Comment: Fixed the sample. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xsl:copy-of` instruction performs [a deep copy](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copy-of); you want to do a shallow one, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="a">
        <xsl:result-document href="a_{@id}.xml">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="a/a"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

> What would I need to do if I wanted to change something like the value
>   of a specific attribute when processing?

Use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:copy-of` and have a matching template to perform the change - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="a">
        <xsl:result-document href="a_{@id}.xml">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="a/a"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <a id="{@id}(moved)">
        <xsl:value-of select="'new value'"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```